# Flutter Just_Audio playing asset files does not recognise file changes

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I am using the following code:

```
   AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();
   await player.setAsset('$soundFolder/words/1/102.mp3');
   await player.play();
```

It works as expected, but if I update (delete and replace with revised content) the file source, `Just_Audio` still plays the existing file.

I tried using `just_audio_cache` clear but no difference.
I tried trying turning the MacBook off and on but no difference.
I tried clearing all the cache files in `Library/Caches` but no difference.

I need to be able to update the files as and when changes are made.

Comment: Did you search the just_audio README for the word "cache"?

Comment: Did you search the just_audio README? I regret I did not, I have used just_audio for some time so looked at issue first then google search. You are right though, the anwser is await AudioPlayer.clearAssetCache();

Comment: You might consider writing up an answer to your question, and marking it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Ryan Heise the solution is very simple:

```
AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();
await AudioPlayer.clearAssetCache();
await player.setAsset('$soundFolder/words/1/102.mp3');
await player.play();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).